# I have a query, while executing the below code, i'm getting type error "Int object is not iterable"

Tags: python-3.x

However i try to understand using pythontutor, i'm getting error at Zip Argument.

```
probs = [0.315, 0.226, 0.289, 0.087, 0.083]
paper = [533, 486, 386, 234, 263]
demand_paper2= 0
for probs, paper in zip (probs, paper):
    demand_paper2 = demand_paper2 + probs * paper    
print( 'Expected demand: ' + str(demand_paper2))    
var1 = sum([prob * (d- demand_paper2)**2 
         for prob, d in zip(probs, demand_paper2)])
std1 = var1 ** 0.5                                  
print('The standard deviation of demand: {0:0.3f}'.format(std1))
```

Comment: IndentationError on `         for prob, d in zip(probs, demand_paper2)])`

Comment: NameError on `d` in `var1 = sum([prob * (d- demand_paper2)**2`

Comment: @PatrickArtner: I get the error described in the question title. Your issues must come from entering the multi-line list comprehension inside the `sum` call as two separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues, both with this call: `zip(probs, demand_paper2)`

The first issue is that you've accidentally rebound the `probs` variable in your first loop. So instead of the original list you bind it to at the start of the code, it contains just a single value now (the last value from the list).

The second issue is with the other argument to `zip`. The `demand_paper2` variable is a single number, so it can't be iterated either. I think you want to be iterating on the original `paper` list, which isn't available, but at least this simplifies the problem to just two variables with the same problem.

The fix for the whole issue is just to pick new variable names. If you don't use the same names for the lists as the variables in the first loop, you'll be OK.

```
probs = [0.315, 0.226, 0.289, 0.087, 0.083]
papers = [533, 486, 386, 234, 263]                  # renamed this variable
demand_paper2= 0
for prob, paper in zip (probs, papers):             # and use prob and papers here
    demand_paper2 = demand_paper2 + prob * paper    
print( 'Expected demand: ' + str(demand_paper2))    
var1 = sum([prob * (d- demand_paper2)**2 
            for prob, d in zip(probs, papers)])     # refer to the papers list here
std1 = var1 ** 0.5                                  
print('The standard deviation of demand: {0:0.3f}'.format(std1))
```

The `demand_paper2` variable name is also pretty bad, but I left it as it is, since it's not actually causing any problems right now. But it could be better, like `expected_paper` or something!